# Theoretical order of accuracy (time stepping method applied for advection-diffusion equation)

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, numerical-calculus

**Statement of the problem**

I try to investigate the order of accuracy in the case of using BTCS time stepping method applied to solving unsteady advection-diffusion equation using the finite difference method.

I try to investigate order of accuracy with respect to the mesh spacing and the time step. In other words, I assume that the error could be decomposed in the following way:

$$
error = O(\Delta x^{p}) + O(\Delta q^{q})
$$

where $p$, $q$ are some natural numbers to be determined

**What is known**

I know that BTCS scheme can be written as:

$$
\frac{\boldsymbol{c}^{n+1} - \boldsymbol{c}^{n}}{\Delta t} = A\boldsymbol{c}^{n+1}
$$

where:

- $c^{n}$ refers to $n$-th state of the system in the computation
- matrix $A$ is defined as

$$
A := -\frac{U}{\Delta x}D_{x} + \frac{\kappa}{(\Delta x)^{2}}D_{xx}
$$

where:

- $U$ refers to advection speed
- $\kappa$ refers to diffusivity constant
- $D_{x}$ refers to advective matrix
- $D_{xx}$ refers to diffusivity matrix
- $\Delta x$ refers to mesh spacing size

**What I tried**

I thought of applying the analysis similar to propagation error that is primarily done in processing experimental results in physics/engineering. However, I am doubtful about this approach.

I manipulated BTCS scheme and got alternative form:
$$
c^{n + 1} = (I - \Delta t A)^{-1} c^{n}
$$

I know that applying this equation $n$ times one may obtain the following equation:

$$
c^{n} = (I - \Delta t A)^{-n} c^{0}
$$

However, I am not sure what to do next, i.e. I am not sure whether to apply Taylor series for multivariable function and proceed further.

Actually speaking, I do not have intuition how to proceed further.

**From computer simulation I obtain linear dependency for $\Delta t$ and quadratic dependency for $\Delta x$. However, I may be wrong**.

Any help how to proceed would be very appreciated!!!